# Steam API "GetOwnedGames" no longer shows every game

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I have a small website and a Discord bot showing me and my friends' games and achievements. I get this data from the Steam "GetOwnedGames" API. Recently some of our games are missing from our respective game libraries.

In particular, I had wondered why this game wouldn't show up https://store.steampowered.com/app/1603980/If_On_A_Winters_Night_Four_Travelers/ when I added it but had forgotten about it for a while, thinking that it could be linked to the game being free and me not having started it. Since then I've played and got all the achievements on this one https://store.steampowered.com/app/1683860/Eronoctosis_Put_Yourself_Together/ (probably NSFW) and this one too doesn't appear either. In both cases the game is free.

I use this URL : http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=KEY&steamid=STEAMID&format=json and have checked that they really don't show up in the results using my own Steam ID.

Are there fellow users of this API, or any idea on this?

Thanks!

Comment: They do appear in my library but not in the results of that request, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Try  `http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=KEY&steamid=STEAMID&format=json&include_played_free_games=1`